# PNP base transistor

Tags: transistors

So I am making a small digital clock using a grid of LEDs and multiplexing. My question is, when testing my grid, the pnp transistors would turn on only when there was a resistor between base and ground. Now I understand having no base resistor is a bad practice, however should the transistor still turn on at least because there should exist a EB current? The transistors are not broken as the last thing I did was with the resistor and they worked. Thank you for any answers, and I am fairly new to all this so if I've done something completely wrong let me know

Comment: If you don't limit the base current you may well destroy the transistor. It might fail on or off, depending (partly) on how much current is available from your power supply.

Comment: So when the max current is exceeded it will fail in either on or off depending on the transistor? And can it do this but still work afterwards, they all still appear to be working properly with resistors?

Comment: Such damage is typically permanent.

Comment: Ok, well I mean they still appear to be working, is it possible that something else is occurring, and when I connect the base to ground through a resistor the leds turn on, and when left floating, they turn off

Comment: Post a diagram of your real circuit, and the circuit as you used it to see if the transistors work.  There is a circuit editor built in of you edit your question (though not available on mobile devices.)

Comment: Schematic required. If ground is negative and you connect base to it, (with emitter to +V) best case is the power supply shuts down. If the transistors still work, that's what happened.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends what the circuit is intended to do. With PNP the emitter will be on the positive side and the collector will be on the negative side with the load somewhere between those connections, in this case any current from emiitter to base will cause some collector current to flow. How much current will depend on the transistor's Gain (hfe), the base cuurent, the load impedance, and the supply voltage.

Remember the transistor is actually an amplifier, but if you drive the base enough you can forget about the linear amplification and use it as a switch, which you presumably are doing. You don't need a resistor to "ground" as noise is not a problem here. It is not a high impedance input like a MOSFET which often requires a resistor to keep it turned off.

You probably do want a series resistor in the base driver circuit to limit base current to a safe value. This is to protect the tansistor itself or the driver or both. Depending on the devices in question and the circuit configuation you will need to calculate what value the resistor needs to be, in both ohms and watts.

Let's assume you are using an Arduino as the driver, max current for any IO pin is 40mA but 200mA total for the chip . Also assume rows of the LED matrix are driven by high side switches and columns are driven by low side switches. When a LED is on there is about 2 volts across it. if the supply is 5volts there could be about 3volts across each transistor pair maybe about 1.5 volts each and maybe not depending on how you set it up.

Your low side switches are configured as "emitter follower" if you pull the base down to 0volts the thing will turn on if there is any current available from the LED and emitter voltage will be dependant on Gain and base current among other things but let's assume no series resistor and a gain of 100. The LED will require about 20ma so that is the collector current to assume. Base current would be about 200uA (20mA/100) which is not a problem for Arduino.

Emitter voltage is going to be somewhere near 0volts maybe about 0.7v

On the high side, the emitter is at 5volts so a series resisistor is needed since the base will be at about 4.3volts and 200uA will be flowing through it. 22kohm will come pretty close to acheiving this (4.3/0.0002). Power rating is not an issue as it will dissipate less than 1mW. All this assumes that only 1 LED will be on at any moment, and that all transistors have the same gain. In reality you may need to drive the base with more current so the transistor drops the minimum voltage possible and use series resistors on each LED to limit the current. Assume 2volts at 20mA and you have 100Ohms and power dissipation about 40mW so the smallest resistors you can get will be ok e.g. 1/8 watt in through hole type.

Or use resistors in the row or column connection but only if there is only 1 LED on at any time. If there are more on then currents and voltages will change and brightness will vary as a result.

Comment: Thank you, however I'm still confused, my pnp transistors are high side switches with the emitter on the high side and load in between the collector and ground. So when I connect base directly to ground, while I understand may damage the transistor, but shouldn't current flow from emitter to base and thus emitter and collector? But when I try it, current only flows when there is a series base resistor?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply ground the base while emitter is connected to the positive rail then you are basically short circuiting the power supply with a diode which is the base-emitter junction and your load will not see anything. With a resistor of some suitable value, there will be a base voltage approximately 0.7 volts below the positive rail and the collector will supply current to the load. With any luck your supply doesn't have enough current available to destroy the base-emitter junction when you shorted it.

If it has been destroyed they usually start by becoming a short circuit then if things are really bad they explode and become an open circuit. Often very quickly

Comment: Ok thank you, I inderstand now, I don't think the transistor was destroyed as it seems to still be working normally, if they appear to be working should they be ok? Or should I look at replacing them, do they pose a risk of short circuiting in the future because I may have damaged them?

Answer (score 0):

You said your PNP transistors are high side SWITCHES then the bases are probably driven with signals and never connected directly to ground. Then maybe the base signals limit the base current?